# Object Method ( this.age) is showing undefined

Tags: javascript, object

```
const adam = {
    firstName: 'Adam',
    lastName: 'Ayub',
    birthYear: 1992,
    job: 'barista',
    friends: ['Laziz', 'Aziz', 'Murod'],
    hasDriversLicense: true,
    
    calcAge: function () {
        this.age = 2022 - this.birthYear;
        return;
    }
};


console.log(adam.age);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please try to elaborate a bit further on your problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You never run `calcAge` so `this.age` is never assigned